# Boolean indexing on specific data

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to find out how to Boolean index in pandas with a set range, like list slicing in Python.

```
mydata = [{'name': 'John', 'age': 75, 'height': 1.78},
  {'name': 'Paul', 'age': 22, 'height': 1.71},
  {'name': 'John', 'age': 45, 'height': 1.81}]

df = pandas.DataFrame(mydata)
df = df.set_index('name')

print df[df.index == 'John']
```

Changing that last print statement to print all indexes equal to 'John' up to the third item in the dataframe.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How do I change that last print statement to print all indexes equal to 'John' up to the third item in the dataframe

Comment: I'd like to point out that your dataframe only has three items so that is exactly what you are doing, you may want to make a better example.

Comment: @user6162407 then, i think that my answer should do that :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can print all indexes equal to 'John' up to the third item in the data frame:

```
print df[0:3].ix['John']
```

Comment: Actually I think that's wrong because the second part will slice the columns. Sorry. :)